# complete command by previous input matching in ConEmu

Tags: conemu

I did some search and could not find the function for ConEmu.

let's say I already have 2 input histories like this:

`cmd1 opt1
cmd2 opt2
...`

now i input

`cmd1`

and I would like to automatically complete the opt1 by an input completion function that scroll through the input histories whose sub-string/head-string match current input. Is there a way to do this in ConEmu?

Comment: As I've answered in the issue, completion is not a terminal's function. The shell cares about it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install something like clink [clink](http://mridgers.github.io/clink/)
which then have bash like function that you can search through your input history by `ctrl+r` or `ctrl+s`